# Como ler múltiplos SoapObject de um WebService?

Tags: java, ksoap2

Estou tentando consumir um Web Service em Java utilizando KSoap 2 na versão 3.4.0.

Quando faço um busca sem parâmetros ele retorna o resultado esperado porem quando faço uma busca passando um parâmetro `addProperty` ele apresenta o erro na linha que recebe a resposta do WS:

```
Vector<SoapObject> resposta = (Vector<SoapObject>)envelope.getResponse();
```

Aparece o erro:

> org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject cannot be cast to java.util.Vector

Comment: Não conheço essa tecnologia, mas o erro parece bem claro: parece que você tem um objeto `SoapObject` e não um `Vector<SoapObject>` . Já tentou fazer assim: `SoapObject resposta = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();` ?

Comment: Pablo obrigado pela resposta, fiz como você me falou e funciona porém só traz o primeiro registro, eu pensei num Vector para trazer os todo o array. Por exemplo quando eu passo um UF para o WS me retorna todas as cidades daquele UF entendeu? Não sei se existe uma outra forma de fazer isso.

Comment: Entendi. Tomei a liberdade de editar o seu título para esclarecer qual é sua dúvida. Não conheço KSoap 2, mas sugiro que pesquise sobre como ler múltiplos `SoapObject`, já que parece ser esse o seu problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri o problema real do meu código quando eu fiz o teste que do Juven_v: quando o WS me retornava um único resultado apresentava o erro de `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject cannot be cast to java.util.Vector`
porque eu estava tentando passar um único SoapObject para um Vector.
O que eu fiz então, tratei a exceção, ou seja, cada quando ele não conseguir cast para o Vector eu mando no catch ele passar para um único SoapObject pois só veio um resultado do WS. Não sei se é a forma mais prática ou a de melhor performace mais é o que tem por enquanto e ta resolvendo.
Segue abaixo o código

```
 public ArrayList<CidadesAt> buscarcidades(String uf){
    ArrayList<CidadesAt> resultado = new ArrayList<CidadesAt>();
    SoapObject buscacidade = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,buscarcidsat);
    buscacidade.addProperty("uf", uf);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(buscacidade);
    envelope.implicitTypes =true;
    HttpTransportSE http = new HttpTransportSE(Proxy.NO_PROXY,URL,timeout);
    try {
        http.call("urn:" + buscarcidsat, envelope);
        Vector<SoapObject> resposta = (Vector<SoapObject>) envelope.getResponse();//se vier um vetor segue daqui
         if(resposta != null) {
            for (SoapObject so : resposta) {
                CidadesAt cidades = new CidadesAt();
                cidades.setCidade(so.getProperty(0).toString());
                resultado.add(cidades);
            }
        }
    }catch( java.lang.ClassCastException e) {//trata aqui caso tenha Exception de cast quer dizer que foi so um registro
        e.printStackTrace();
        try {
            SoapObject resposta = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
            if (resposta != null) {
                CidadesAt cidades = new CidadesAt();
                cidades.setCidade(resposta.getProperty(0).toString());
                resultado.add(cidades);
            }
            return resultado;
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }catch (Exception e3) {//outro tipo de Exception
        e3.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
return resultado;
}
```

é isso ai obrigado a todos e abraço.

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade você não pode fazer uma conversão do tipo de retorno do método getResponse() para um vector. O que pode ser feito é um cast para SoapObject e depois acessar as propriedades (atributos) do objeto criado.

```
SoapObject resposta = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
SoapPrimitive atributo1 = (SoapPrimitive) reposta.getProperty(0); //pode ser um indice ou uma chave
String atributo_string = atributo1.toString();
```

Se o método getResponse() fosse um vetor de objetos (ou sub vetores) ficaria assim:

```
SoapObject resposta = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
SoapObject atributo1_vetor = (SoapObject) reposta.getProperty(0); //pode ser um indice ou uma chave
SoapPrimitive atributo1 = (SoapPrimitive) atributo1_vetor.getProperty(0); //pode ser um indice ou uma chave
String atributo_string = atributo1.toString();
```

Você pode consultar a documentação da biblioteca [ksoap](http://kobjects.org/ksoap2/doc/api/)

Comment: Obrigado por responde Juven_v foi bem útil.